# AbpException: Could not find the bundle file '/libs/abp/utils/abp-utils.umd.min.js' from IWebContentFileProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've started getting the following error when I try to login after upgrading to the current version 2.62

AbpException: Could not find the bundle file '/libs/abp/utils/abp-utils.umd.min.js' from IWebContentFileProvider

Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bundling.TagHelpers.AbpTagHelperResourceService.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output, List bundleItems, string bundleName)

Many thanks

zak

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if this is still relevant to you, but this is how I fixed the same problem after updating to 5.2

I Run `yarn` and `abp install-libs` in the root directory

Hope it helps

Comment: Note that when you run `abp install-libs` if you get a warning that looks like this: `npm WARN config global --global, --local are deprecated. Use --location=global instead` then follow the solutions offered in this post: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4980